# If the transformation is not onto, does that mean that it is not one to one?

Tags: linear-algebra

If transformation T: V -> V and it is not onto, then nullity is not 0

So, it seems like it is not one-to-one when it is not onto.

And, If transformation is onto, is it one to one? because nullity is 0 ?

Comment: No, the identity map is both one-to-one and onto.

Comment: What is $V$?  What is $T$?  Speaking of "nullity" suggests you have a vector space and a linear transformation in mind, but you do not make this clear.  Please edit your Question.

Comment: It’s pretty clear from your use of the word “nullity” that you were thinking of $T$ as a linear transformation of a vector space $V$. You should have said this, and also specified whether $V$ was to be finite-dimensional or not.

Answer (score 1):

If (as I assume you mean) $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $T: V \to V$ is a linear map, then the Rank-Nullity law gives that
$$\text{rank } T + \text{null } T = \dim V,$$
and so in particular
$$T \text{ is onto} \Leftrightarrow T \text{ is one-to-one} \Leftrightarrow \text{rank } T = \dim V \Leftrightarrow \text{null } T = 0.$$

If $V$ is infinite-dimensional, this no longer need be the case. For example, consider the vector space $S$ of sequences in, e.g., $\mathbb{R}$; the right-shift transformation $R: S \to S$ defined by
$$R(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) := R(0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$$
is linear and one-to-one (it has a left inverse, namely the obvious *left-shift* transformation) but is not onto (the first term of any sequence in the image is $0$).

Comment: What If two spaces have different dimensions?  I mean If T maps x in 3 vector space to 2 vector space or vice versa?

Comment: Then it's not a map of the form $T: V \to V$. If $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, then a map $T: V \to W$ cannot be onto if $\dim V < \dim W$, and it cannot be one-to-one if $\dim V > \dim W$.

Answer (score 0):

They are different concepts. Either can hold or both or neither.

$f: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$

$f(x) = x+ 1,$

is one-one (injective) but not onto (surjective.)

Answer (score 0):

1) $1-1$ but not onto: inclusion of a proper subspace into its superspace space, e.g., $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 : x \rightarrow (x,0)$.

2) Onto, but not $1-1$: Opposite direction: Projection map from superspace into subspace, e.g., $L: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R : (x,y) \rightarrow x $.